# How to pan when zoomed in on something on mac?

Tags: macos, mac

In mac I press the command key then I can zoom with my trackpad using two fingers on my trackpad. (this is set in system prefs -> accessibility -> zoom)

But when I'm zoomed in on something, is there a way to pan? or can I just zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pan by moving your mouse beyond the edges of the zoomed area. This moves the zoomed area to follow the mouse.

If, in System Preferences → Accessibility → Zoom, you also have ‘Zoom follows the keyboard focus’ then as you type the zoomed area will follow the typing if typing beyond the edge of the zoomed area.

Comment: This is unfortunate. Using screen edges can be difficult with multiple monitors. I find that I am often zooming during remote coding session when someone else is streaming video, so neither of these approaches are very useful. I wish there was another keyboard binding that would let you pan the zoomed screen. --- You can cheat a bit by utilizing the fact that the zoom will center on your pointer. So, by quickly zooming out, repositioning your mouse, and then zooming in, you can sort of pan around, but this is not a great solution either.

Comment: @spkane https://apple.com/feedback

Answer (score 1):

There is a Zoom option in Accessibility settings to keep the mouse pointer in the center of the screen. Will that solve your issue?

1. System Preferences > Accessibility
2. Click Zoom
3. At the bottom of the windows, by Zoom Settings, select options.
4. For "With Zoomed in, the screen image moves:", set to "So the pointer is at or near the center of the screen".

[Zoom Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru1GQ.jpg)

Comment: Nice answer. Welcome to Super User!